# svg animate not working on ios

Tags: ios, svg, jquery-animate

here is my svg animation...its working everywhere but ios (safari or chrome)

```
<svg width="44" height="44" viewBox="0 0 44 44" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke="#519ecb">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width="2">
        <circle cx="22" cy="22" r="1">
            <animate attributeName="r" begin="0s" dur="2.5s" values="1; 20" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1"/>
            <animate attributeName="stroke-opacity" begin="0s" dur="2.5s" values="1; 0" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.3, 0.61, 0.355, 1" />
        </circle>
        <circle cx="22" cy="22" r="1">
            <animate attributeName="r" begin="-0.9s" dur="2.5s" values="1; 20" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1" />
            <animate attributeName="stroke-opacity" begin="-0.9s" dur="2.5s" values="1; 0" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0; 1" keySplines="0.3, 0.61, 0.355, 1" />
        </circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

each animate tag has repeatCount="indefinite" attr but I couldnt write here on code view because of stackoverflow post rules...Its very hard to ask something here...